# Accidentally deleted Bridging-Header.h file

Tags: objective-c, swift

I accidentally deleted Bridging-Header.h file from my project and move to trash. Now if i am running the app it is showing an error "Bridging-Header.h' does not exist"

Comment: Try to find in trash and after that right click choose put back option

Comment: just recover it from your repo?

Comment: If Git is not your best friend yet... it is, starting from now. Just do it. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Select the project in the project navigator
- Select the target in the project window
- Select `Build Settings`
- Type <kbd>bridg</kbd> in the search field
- In the line `Objective-C Bridging Header` memorize file name and path.
- Press <kbd>⌘N</kbd>
- Create new `Header File` for the proper platform
- Name it according to the memorized file name and save it to the memorized path.

And you are strongly encouraged to use Source Control. It's worth it ...